# Google Sheet Expression

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I need a way to "send" the value of one cell to another cell on a different sheet. the catch is the expression cannot be in either of those 2 cells.

i was trying something like =IF(B2<>C1,VLOOKUP(A2,'Part Data'!E:H,4)=B2)

A2 = the reference for the lookup (in this instance its a part #)

B2 = the value i want moved to the vlookup location

C1= the value currently in the vlookup location (using another vlookup to pull that value from the other sheet)

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
=IF(B2<>C1, VLOOKUP(A2, 'Part Data'!E:H, 4, 0)=B2)
```

which will give you TRUE or FALSE